# Why Bootstrap cdn jsdelivr don't open?

Tags: bootstrap-5

Is jsdelivr cdn down?

Bootstrap CDN gives me Hmmm… can't reach this page so that affects many websites' design.

Please help me to solve this problem.

I'm from Egypt.

I expected to get the Bootstrap CSS or JS from the CDN but it gives me "Hmmm… can't reach this page".

[image: CDN status]
[image: CD Error]

But If I made VPN it opens !!! what should I do? when I upload the files to google drive its making lag.

Comment: Try a different browser or clearing your cookies. What browser are you using, by the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For who has problem in Bootstrap cdn jsdelivr doesn't open because it's blocked from his/ her country you can try this solution:

Change .com to .xyz it will be Open

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

I'm also in Egypt and encountered the same problem yesterday and it loaded after using vpn.
I guess it doesn't work in Egypt?
I had to download the bootstrap files and use it locally on my project

Comment: It's blocked there. See my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76643926/22152755).

Answer (score 3):

jsdeliver cdn is blocked both in Egypt (since june 2023) and China (May 2022)

Try using other cdns

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34869581)

Comment: @RamChander what are your concerns about this answer?