# cdn.jsdelivr.net links not working in my country

Tags: javascript, cdn

cdn.jsdelivr.net links used to work / load fine past week and then out of the sudden It stopped working for no entire reason at all and I don't know what's the cause. I've looked every where It seems like there was a person that had the same problem as me and I figured I would ask here again maybe I could get an answer. i also live in egypt as him so maybe me living here is the cause or it got blocked.

links like https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ won't load for me but jsdelivr.com works so im just confused

Answer (score 9):

The `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/` domain is blocked in a number of countries including Egypt and China. It has been blocked in China since about May 2022 and in Egypt since about June 2023.

You have to either use your files locally or search other alternatives like [UNPKG](https://www.unpkg.com/) or [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/).

In fact, the `https://jsdelivr.com` domain isn't blocked.