# I tried cdn-bootstrap link in my projects and it didn't work, why?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

``<!DOCTYPE html>

```
<!-- another link is not working-->
```

```
Bootstrap Example



  <h1>Bootstrap Example</h1>
  
    This is a primary alert.
  
  Click Me
  
    
      Email address
      
    
    
      Password
      
    
    Submit
  
  
    <a href="#">Navbar</a>
    
      
    
    
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

`

`When using bootstrap 5 link does not work when using bootstrap 4 link works, why!?`
 And this is the answer of Chad GBT

If the Bootstrap CDN link is not working, there could be a few possible reasons:

Network connectivity: Ensure that you have a stable internet connection. If you're experiencing network issues, the CDN link may not load properly.
Typo or incorrect link: Double-check the CDN link to make sure there are no typos or missing characters. Verify that the link is correct and points to a valid Bootstrap CSS file.
Content Security Policy (CSP) restrictions: Some websites may have Content Security Policy (CSP) settings in place that restrict the loading of external resources. In such cases, you may need to modify the CSP settings or consider hosting the Bootstrap files locally.
If you can provide more details about the issue you're facing or any error messages you're receiving, I can help troubleshoot further.`

`

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- another link is not working-->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--     
      but this link is working!
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    -->

Comment: i think this bug from my pc , because when try this code in codepen with vpn it was working ,, so do have any way fixing this bug in my pc

Comment: At a very very high guess, you're living in the Middle East or Egypt? `https://jsdelivr.net` cdn is blocked there. Anything else should work correctly.

Comment: Also, see my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76643926/22152755).

Comment: yes, i'm from egypt, and thanks for your answer. @LightningMcQueen